# How to rotate an image with multiple points and angles?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I want to straighten the inclined text in the image. I was able to get contours and angle of rotation for each contour. I have formed a box around each contour and also have x-y cordinates of four corners of the box. I am trying to figure out how to rotate each box of contour according to the data point and angle associated with it. I have been trying to replicate the code below according to my task, but couldn't get it to work.

```
new_image = cv2.imread(image_path)

(h, w) = new_image.shape[:2]

center = (w // 2, h // 2)

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)

new_image = cv2.warpAffine(new_image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

cv2.imshow(new_image)`
```

Comment: What problem/error do you get?

Comment: I am getting a cv::remap error when I try to fit the coordinates of the box for warpAffine().